# pytest issue with pandera

Tags: pytest, importerror, python-3.10, pandera

I wrote a test to experiment with `pandera` for `DataFrame` validation. I put the validation schema in a `pytest` fixture and passed it to the unit test I had. Now, I have this odd issue: when I pip install `pandera` into my virtual environment, `pytest` stops workings, the entire test suite fails to run (not just this one test), and I get this import error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Config' from 'pytest'`

I'm using python3.10.

I do have an `__init__.py` file in my test folder, but that was not an issue before. I only get this error when I install `pandera`

I blew the virtual environment and created a fresh one without `pandera` installed, and the other unit tests I had in the suite passed just fine. Installed `pandera` and the same import error showed up.

Has anybody run into this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem using pytest `6.2.5`. It seems the issue appears with `pandera` versions >= `0.15.0`. Downgrading pandera to `0.14.5` "solved" the issue for me.

That's no permanent solution, though. I'll open an issue for pandera, hoping someone can fix it soon.

Edit: the the currently latest pytest version `7.4.0` also seems to work with pandera >=`0.15.0`

Comment: [Here is the related pandera issue](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/1272)